# mariadb - I know who the boss of the employee is. But how do I figure out the boss of the boss?

Tags: database, recursion, join, mariadb, self-join

I'm using self-join in mariaDB. I figured out how to know who the boss of the employee is. But how do I figure out the boss of the boss? Can I self-join multiple times? Or do I use recursion or something else?

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        employees.first_name,
        ' ',
        employees.last_name
    ) AS employee,
    CONCAT(
        supv.first_name,
        ' ',
        supv.last_name
    ) AS boss
FROM
    employees
LEFT JOIN employees AS supv
ON
    employees.manager_id = supv.employee_id;
```

I tried the above code, but how do I get the boss of of the boss? Can I self-join multiple time? Or do I use recursion or something else?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43pko.png)

Comment: Yes you can self join multiple times for a boss of a boss. If the problem truly is iterative, then you can use recursive CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(level1.first_name, ' ', level1.last_name) AS Level_1
    ,CONCAT(level2.first_name, ' ', level2.last_name) AS Level_2
    ,CONCAT(level3.first_name, ' ', level3.last_name) AS Level_3
    ,CONCAT(level4.first_name, ' ', level4.last_name) AS Level_4
    ,CONCAT(level5.first_name, ' ', level5.last_name) AS Level_5
    ,CONCAT(level6.first_name, ' ', level6.last_name) AS Level_6
FROM
    employees AS level1
RIGHT JOIN employees AS level2 ON level1.employee_id = level2.manager_id
RIGHT JOIN employees AS level3 ON level2.employee_id = level3.manager_id
RIGHT JOIN employees AS level4 ON level3.employee_id = level4.manager_id
RIGHT JOIN employees AS level5 ON level4.employee_id = level5.manager_id
RIGHT JOIN employees AS level6 ON level5.employee_id = level6.manager_id

ORDER BY level1.last_name,level2.last_name,level3.last_name,level4.last_name,level5.last_name;
```